# how to implement auto redirect feature in paypal

Tags: paypal

I have implemented the payment button code in the AAA Shuttles site. The client wants to use the auto redirect feature, so that when the payment is complete, then the user should be redirected to our site after 5-20 sec without having to click a "return to AAA Shuttles" link.

I have implemented the auto return feature, but it is not working. Here is what I did; please have a look and guide me with the best solution:

1. Activate auto return feature form paypal account.
2. Add a link:  http://aaashuttles.com.au/transactionConfirmed.php
3. And then add code for my paypal button such as:

   ```
   <form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post"/>
   <!-- <form action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post"/>  -->
     <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_cart"/>
     <input type="hidden" name="upload" value="1"/>
     <input type="hidden" name="business" value="clientemail@aaashuttles.com.au"/> 
     <input type="hidden" name="item_name_1" value="<?php echo $itemname;?> TransactionId Is <?php echo $transactionid;?>"/>
     <input type="hidden" name="amount_1" value="<?php echo $amount;?>"/> 
     <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="AUD"/>
     <input type="hidden" name="return" value="<?php echo SITE_URL.'/paypalpaymentsuccess.php?transactionIds='.$booking_id; ?>&Agentid=<?php echo $agentcode;?>"/> 
     <input type="text" name="bookingtype" value="<?php echo $directions; ?>"/>  -->
     <input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" value="<?php echo SITE_URL.'/paypalpaymentfailed.php? transactionIds ='.$get_booking_ids.'&quotetype='.$get_booking_type.'  '; ?>"/>
     <input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="<?php echo SITE_URL.'/ transactionConfirmed.php;?>"/>
     <input type="hidden" name="rm" value="2">
     <input type="submit" class="submit_right" value="Proceed to payment"/>
   </form>
   ```
4. Click on the "pay now" button
5. Enter a paypal username and pwd
6. Now the "review your information" page appears, then click "pay now"
7. Now the "thanks for your order" page appears. On this page, I see a link to "return to arjunsign@gmail.com".
8. After I click on this link, I have a page with the following message:

   ```
   Thanks for your order
   Thanks for your order
   Your payment of $4.00 AUD is complete.
   If you are not redirected within 10 seconds, . 
   PayPal. The safer, easier way to pay.
   For more information, read our User Agreement and Privacy Policy.  Test Site
   ```
9. And, at last, after 10 seconds, the page is redirected to ours.

But I don’t want to click the link to redirect that is mentioned in step 7 ("return to arjunsign@gmail.com"), I need use the auto return feature without clicking the link given in step 7.

Please give me some suggestions and guidance about where I am wrong.

Comment: oops, I clicked that link  http://aaashuttles.com.au/transactionConfirmed.php   and it wrote that  I paid. I 'm sorry.(